# Are there C library resources similar to C++'s Boost library?

Tags: c

I don't ever recall coming across anything for C that's as extensive as C++'s Boost library.

Comment: @djechlin I don'tthink you ought to punish OP this way. He is supposed to accept whichever answer he found the best. +1.

Comment: @H2CO3 and djechlin is supposed to vote up/down as long as he has a reason for it that he considers valid

Comment: @djechlin can you provide a correct answer?

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/116650

Comment: @becko - glib, the answer posted by agateau with 8 upvotes currently, came to mind.  I believe Brian Stewart's answer was accepted at the time of my comment, or possibly the two-word "There isn't."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do there is APR (The Apache Portable Runtime library) which is what the Apache http daemon is built on

http://apr.apache.org/

For GUI, there is wxWidgets (formerly wxWindows)

http://www.wxwidgets.org/

Answer (score 18):

You can have a look at glib. It provides quite a few interesting things like containers, unicode support, threading...

Have a look at [its documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/)

Comment: GLib is a bit more like the STL, rather than boost.  But a good choice either way.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen anything. Really, C++ templates are the enabling technology for STL and much of boost, and C doesn't have them. I've seen many C-interface libraries for things like image processing, 3D graphics, networking, etc., but never a real general-purpose library like boost. You can find pieces though - threading libraries, string libraries, etc. - that are similar to sections of boost.

Answer (score 1):

Glib does compensate it partially in form of various unicode, string types. If you add Gobject you could get some object programming even some garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

ACE (Adaptive Communication Environment) is sometimes mentioned. It's not quite an apples-to-apples comparison. Boost provides more "basic building blocks" whereas ACE provides more of an tightly integrated framework geared towards telco products. I have used both extensively and I find Boost vastly superior. One big advantage of Boost is that many of its features will show up in the STL extensions for the upcoming C++0x standard (see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1).

Answer (score 0):

or you can look at ccan http://ccan.ozlabs.org/

but no, there really isn't any complete package, glib comes closest